# ARC struggle in AFNetworking

Tags: ios, json, xcode, afnetworking

I'm using AFNetworking in my app. After I have imported the files and build the app I get like 90 errors, complaining on the ARC mode.

```
ARC forbids explicit message send of 'autorelease'
```

I've tried to go to **Edit** -> **Refractor** -> **Convert to Objective-C ARC**

But then I got:

```
Cannot Convert to Objective-C ARC

Xcode found 93 issues that prevent conversion from proceeding.  Fix all ARC readiness issues and try again.
```

I don't get this...

Comment: The latest version of AFNetworking is built using ARC. What version did you install?

Comment: So what's your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you download AFNetworking 2.0.

Comment: Ok, so I've downloaded 2.0. It seems like I have to change some things. I get the error: Use of undeclared identifier 'AFJSONRequestOperation' on: AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {

Comment: Look through the api and rewrite your methods. You probably copied those from some forum using afnetworking 1.0.

Answer (score 4):

Don't attempt to migrate `AFNetworking` to ARC by yourself, either change to a newer version (which uses ARC) or [disable ARC for the `AFNetworking` files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646052/how-can-i-disable-arc-for-a-single-file-in-a-project). Better still use [Cocoapod](http://cocoapods.org/) to manage your dependencies and forget about ARC mismatch problems.

Comment: Here's a [link](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/wiki/Getting-Started-with-AFNetworking) to getting set up with AFNetworking in Cocoapods. Using Cocoapods is a highly recommended approach to managing dependencies in your project.

Answer (score 1):

In the Project Settings, under Build Phases, Compile Sources, select the AFNetworking files and add -fno-objc-arc as the compiler flag. This disables arc for those files.

I definitely agree though. Use Cocoapods or get AFNetworking 2.0 or 1.x with ARC